# Test data for PostgreSQL table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

How I can create test data into PostgreSQL Table using one SQL query? For example I would like to insert several lines of data into this table:

```
CREATE TABLE RELEASE_PLANNING(
 ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
 NAME TEXT,
 PLANNING_START_DATE DATE,
 PLANNING_END_DATE DATE,
 DESCRIPTION TEXT,
 LAST_UPDATE DATE,
 CREATED DATE
)
;
```

I tested this code

```
PreparedStatement ps = null;
        boolean committed = false;
        try
        {
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                int randomNum = 10 + (int) (Math.random() * 20000);
                ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGEBASE (ID, NAME) VALUES (?, generate_series(1,1000), md5(random()::text))");
                ps.setInt(1, randomNum);
//                ps.setString(2, "Test_file");
                ps.executeUpdate();

            }

            ps.close();

            conn.commit();
            committed = true;
        }
```

I get error

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: INSERT has more expressions than target columns
  Position: 7

Comment: The hard way, write several insert statements - with data that makes sense test-wise.

Comment: Ok, but I want to insert 1000 rows of random data. Is there any quick solution?

Comment: My standard trick is to insert 10 rows manually, then do insert into table select from table, with adjusted values. Do that a few times, and you have 1000 rows or more.

Comment: I updated the post. How I can generate random string?

Comment: So, what happened when you tested the code you've added? What went wrong? What does it not do that you want it to?

Comment: I would like to use internal loop into the SQL query and also add string and number random value. How I can do this?

Comment: I updated my post.

Answer (score 3):

The error message correctly tells you that you're trying to insert three columns of data (`?, generate_series(1,1000), md5(random()::text))`) into two columns (`INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGEBASE (ID, NAME)`). It's not clear what this has to do with your `create table` statement, which creates a table of a different name, having seven columns.

This kind of query will insert 100 rows.

```
insert into release_planning
select n, 'a', current_date, current_date, 'a', current_date, current_date
from generate_series (1, 100) n;
```

If you want random data, the best approach is probably to write some functions, and use them in the `select` clause of that statement. So, I might write

- random_integer(low, high),
- random_date(low, high), and
- random_string(length),

and call them like this.

```
insert into release_planning
select n, 
       random_string(35), 
       current_date, 
       random_date(current_date, date '2016-12-31'), 
       random_string(20), 
       random_date(date (current_date + interval '3 days'), date '2016-12-31'), 
       current_date
from generate_series (1, 100) n;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple Data generation:

```
insert into release_planning
select n, 
       substr(concat(md5(random()::text), md5(random()::text)), 0, 35), 
       current_date, 
       current_date + (round(random()*100)::integer), 
       substr(concat(md5(random()::text), md5(random()::text)), 0, 20), 
       current_date + (round(random()*100)::integer),
       current_date + (round(random()*100)::integer)
from generate_series (1, 1000) n;
```